# Set a password for Setup.exe

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, password-protection, setup.exe

I added a Setup Project to my existing Project to make a Setup out of it.
Can I protect this Setup.exe with a password before you can install it?
I'm using Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Why don't you just zip the setup and add a password to the zip file?

Comment: Because I would like to protect the Setup itself. Because as soon as you unzip it with the password and some gets access to it there is no further protection. But looks like I have to use a different programm/method.
But thanks MS_SP @Save

Comment: what you could do is create a dummy form where you have a textbox for the password. if the passwort is correct, just start the setup.exe from code-behind...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following link , if not late

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/659367/Password-Dialog-for-Visual-Studio-Deployment-Proje

Comment: Note that [link-only answers are discouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info), SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the answer is no, you can't.

As suggested in the comments, you could just zip the whole setup and protect that with a password, or use some other third part encryption tool to do so if using winzip is not an option.

The problem with this approach is that, once one person has the key, they can create how many clear copies they want; if that's a problem, you may want to look into some other way to protect your program from piracy.